# Database relation with Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and I'm stuck.  This is what I am struggling with:

```
$questions = Question::find($id)->quiz(); // this code retrieves data from
                                          // the table using the primary key
                                          // in the table. The is a parameter
                                          // that is passed via get.
```

**This is what I have right now:**

```
$questions = Question::where('quiz_id', '=', $id)->quiz();
```

**This is the error I get:**

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::quiz()
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to run a query to get data from my database table using the foreign key in the table not the primary key, I also want to be able to use relations with this as seen from what I tried to do above.

**Edit: Added the Question Model**

```
<?php

class Question extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'quiz_questions';

    public function quiz()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Quiz');
    }

}
```

Comment: what should `->quiz()` do?

Comment: It's in my model,  i just updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the quiz() function from `Question::find($id)->quiz()` will return a Query Builder instance allowing you to query the parent of the Question, its not going to return any data at that point until you call `->get()` or another method that actually executes the query.

If you're wanting to return all the questions belonging to a certain quiz then you can do it like this.

```
$questions = Question::where('quiz_id', $id)->get();
```

This will return an `Eloquent\Collection` of the results for all questions with a `quiz_id` that is equal to `$id`.

If you've setup the relations between the Quiz and Questions then you can also do this using the Laravel relations.

```
$quiz = Quiz::findOrFail($id);

foreach($quiz->questions as $question)
{
    // Do stuff with $question
}
```

Laravel will automagically pull Questions from the database that belongTo the Quiz you've already got from the database, this is known as eager loading http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Thank you soo much, you just thought me a lot, i understand how it works even better now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wader is correct, just calling `where()` will not execute your query. You either call `get()` and get an iterable result or use `first()` if you only want one result.

```
$quiz = Question::where('quiz_id', '=', $id)->first()->quiz();
```